# What can we do with global variables in the console?

Tags: javascript

I've read that, in the console, variables with `let`, `const` or `class`, defined in the 'inner global environment' (I understand this to mean the 'highest' line of code i.e. not scoped in a function) are considered global variables.

In `node.js`, I understood global variables can be **accessed in all files**. Does a global variable in the console have any similar attribute? I already know that it can be accessed anywhere **in** the console. If that's all it means then that's fine.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined with let, const or class are not automatically global variables. It depends on the scope, where you defined them. If they are defined in a function, they are block-scoped (i.e. only usable in that function). Outside of a function, they are globally accessible (for instance, in a function you can use these variables without defining them explicitly) but it is usually not necessary and must be avoided, if possible. Otherwise, it makes future implementations of software much more complex.

Comment: I should've mentioned in my question I've got that concept. I've updated it to reflect that. I know in `node.js` a global variable (such as an `implicit` variable i.e. `x = 5`) is attached to the global scope (for the time that the .js file it's in is run) and that this mean **it can be accessed in all files**. I wanted to know if a global variable in the console has any similar property.

Comment: You know already the answer ;-) ➡ "If that's all it means then that's fine."